# Custom action bar does not fill parent

Tags: android

**Custom action bar does not fill parent.**

I am using custom action bar for navigation drawer purpose.
    But My action bar keep some space left at left side of action bar.

I used code like this.

```
// to inflate custom view

            LayoutInflater inflator=   (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v=inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_top_bar, null);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
            getActionBar().setCustomView(v);

            View v1 = getActionBar().getCustomView();
            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) v1.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
            v1.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

**this is action_custom_action_top_bar file for reference**

this xml file contains main linear layout with left and right imageviews for opening two sided drawers respectively. but addition space get occured
 on left side of the action bar can any one help me out?

this is custom action bar i have used in that some background colour
 i have given to the action bar and two image for each side for drawers

```
   <LinearLayout                 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IV_leftIcon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:background="@color/light_green"
            android:src="@drawable/header_menu_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/actionText"
            style="@style/action_bar_top_text_size"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".6"
            android:background="@color/light_green"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/header_dropdown_arrow"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sample"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IV_rightIcon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:background="@color/light_green"
            android:src="@drawable/plus_btn" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hey AmaJayJB please see the xml file that i posted recently.

Comment: remove gravity center , make width match parent

Comment: Change linearLayout to RelativeLayout

Comment: Try to remove the android:layout_gravity="center" property from the root Linearlayout.

Comment: I agree with removing layout_gravity="center", but I wouldn't automatically change to a RelativeLayout. Have you looked at the new design library stuff? It is very useful in setting up action bar stuff. Also I would recommend using the supportActionBar rather than actionBar

Comment: mina fawzy and Luksprog.. i tried all things but still not working...i think issue is related with theme of application. I am using appcompat v7.

Comment: I update my answer please try it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

how make action bar fill width

> UPDATED ANSWER

remove android:layout_gravity="center" in root linear to be like this , make height wrap_content

```
<LinearLayout                 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" > 

      ......
</LinearLayout>
```

Prefer use getSupportActionBar() as default activity extends ActionBarActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));



    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v, layoutParams);
    Toolbar parent = (Toolbar) v.getParent();
    parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);

}
}
```

> Summary

I understand why you have a problem , you using eclipse with old support library
that dosenot support ToolBar
use [appcompat-v21](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) or later

my advice to you , use Android studio as they stop support eclipse

this code working 100% , prove of concept

[image]

Comment: i tried it...again same result...can u give me ur mailid ...so that i can send it  to u.

Comment: gentel_mina2011@yahoo.com

Comment: mina fawzy ...thanks for your reply...but toolbar parent requires api level 21....we are setting min sdk version to 14....so this will not work with us

Comment: i wil send u the code through mail..please help me...thanks

Comment: support library v7 appcompat-v21 , use android studio

Comment: Can Any one know why sherlockfragmentactivity cannot resolve oncreate method

Answer (score 5):

Just add these 2 line code into your Toolbar xml code

```
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
```

It will solve your problem.

Here is my working code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">
    <include layout="@layout/your_custom_toolbar_layout"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```